# Perl array reference containing the number of keys in a hash, not the actual keys

Tags: perl

There is a twist obviously. When I do it like that it works and contains all the keys:

```
my $hash = {};
$$hash{1} = "asd";
$$hash{21} = "fafafa";

for my $key (keys($hash))
{
    push($arr_ref, $key);
}

print Dumper($arr_ref);
```

However when I try to do it the following way I only get the number of the keys:

```
    my $hash = {};
    $$hash{1} = "asd";
    $$hash{21} = "fafafa";
    my $arr_ref = [];
    $arr_ref = keys($hash);
```

In my head both things should be the same and after all if I do it like that:

```
my @arr = keys($hash);
```

`@arr` will contain the keys of the hash.
The question is where is the difference ?

Comment: You are confused about the nature of Perl's variable typing. For example, the line `my $hash = {};` has absolutely no purpose in both your examples. Remove that line and it will make no difference. A Perl variable is the type of whatever was last assigned to it. So although the line `my $arr_ref = [];` makes `$arr_ref` a reference to an array at that point, the line `$arr_ref = keys($hash)` provides a scalar context to `keys()`, resulting in the length of the array being returned. It needs to be `@$arr_ref = keys($hash)` to provide an array context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few things confused here. If the sigil (the sign in front of the var name) is a `$`, you have a *scalar* value.

Here is a list of things you need to remember:

- Both `$hash` and `$arr_ref` are references, so the variable names have a `$` because they only store a memory address reference to where the actual hash/array is.
- An array has a `@` sigil, and a hash has a `%` sigil. So `@array` and `%hash` are both **not** references.
- If you want to put a data structure into another data structure in Perl, you need to reference it. This is done by putting a `\` in front of the variable name like `$ref = \@array`.
- An array gets a list assigned: `my @colors = ( 'red', 'green' );`
- A hash gets a list (with parenthesis) assigned: `%count = ( 'red' => 5, 'green' => 2 );`
- To access a hash value, use `$count{'red'}`. The sigil changes to `$` because the value behind the whole identifier `count{'red'}` is now a scalar value.
- To access an array value, use `$colors[0]` (which will give `'red'`.
- The `keys` function returns a list.
- Forcing a list or an array into scalar context will give its number of elements.

Now with all this knowledge you will see that when you assign `keys($hash)` to `$arr_ref`, you are forcing scalar context, thus you get the count.

- If you want an array of the keys, use `my @array = keys($hash)`.
- If you want an array ref, use `my $arr_ref = \keys($hash)` or put the list that is returned by `keys` into an array ref like `my $arr_ref = [ keys($hash) ]`.

Also note that Perl's [`keys` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/funtions/keys.html) only recently learned to handle references. You should be giving it a hash, or dereference your hash ref like `keys( %{ $hash_ref } )`. This can be shortened to `keys %$hash_ref`.

Also, always `use strict` and `use warnings` as both will help you by telling you about things you did wrong or things that you might have gotten confused.

---

To illustrate some more, I have rewritten your first piece of code to three different forms.

No references:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
  1  => "asd",
  21 => "fafafa"
);

my @array_of_keys = ();
for my $key ( keys %hash )
{
  push @array_of_keys, $key;
}

print Dumper( \@array_of_keys ); # reference the array because it looks nicer in Dumper
```

Reference for the array:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
  1  => "asd",
  21 => "fafafa"
);

my $arrayref_of_keys = [];
for my $key ( keys %hash )
{
  push @$arrayref_of_keys, $key; # or @{ $foo }
}

print Dumper( $arrayref_of_keys ); # it's already a ref, so no need for \
```

All references:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hashref = {    # notice the curly braces instead of round parens
  1  => "asd",
  21 => "fafafa"
};

my $arrayref_of_keys = [];
for my $key ( keys %$hashref )   # or %{ $foo }
{
  push @$arrayref_of_keys, $key; # or @{ $foo }
}

print Dumper( $arrayref_of_keys );
```

---

I suggest you read [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: It just got more detailed ;)

Comment: As a side note, think about when you want to use references and when you do not need to.

Comment: It is a good side note, I am just experimenting with them now so I understand them better.

Answer (score 3):

`use strict;` would be helpful along with `use warnings;`, try

```
@$arr_ref = keys($hash);
```

as `$arr_ref = keys($hash);` is implicit version of `$arr_ref = scalar keys($hash);` and ensures scalar [`context`](http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl) in both cases.

Also notice that `keys $scalar` is [experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), and `keys %$scalar` is advised.